# What is the wordpress Git hub Repo master on beta?

Tags: github

I am fairly new to Wordpress and have started checking out the latest version from Github. I assumed that the latest version would be master but it seems the latest is 3.9-branch

1. Is the 3.9 branch the correct one to use?
2. Can I revert to the production version if I have installed beta on a site?
3. Is the Github version of Wordpress always up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what gave you the idea 3.9 is latest, looking at [Branches · WordPress/WordPress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/branches) it hadn't had commits in 3 months.

1. Correct for what? If you want trunk then use master branch from GitHub.
2. Typically you can, but it's matter of probability and not guaranteed. WP won't roll back any upgrade changes (such as database schema changes) on downgrade, but they are rarely breaking in such scenario.
3. Yes, it is automatically updated and receives latest commits in minutes after SVN.

Comment: Rarst: 1- Correct for production - Thanks for you answer

Comment: @brentwpeterson for production using the latest stable version would make sense by definition. Stable releases are marked via tags, not branches.